# Javascript onclick events for playing/pausing a video not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my web page I have embedded background music and a background video (webm format). I am trying to make play/pause button **images** (png) work for both the video and the music, however, both do not work.

I have added the background music via embed and with id *music*:

```
<embed src="resources/bgsound.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" hidden="true" id="music">
```

I do not want to use the UI, simply because of the design and I want to keep using the two buttons, which are images in .png format.
The video I have added in the following way:

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="resources/csgotrailer.png" id="bgvid">
<source src="resources/csgotrailer.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

And these are the images, that are supposed to work as buttons:

```
<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play" height="30" width="30" id="play">
<img src="images/pause.png" alt="Pause" height="30" width="30" id="pause">
```

(with two respective IDs). This is the CSS of the two images, not that it matters (or so I believe):

```
#play {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    opacity: 0.175;
}
#pause {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5%;
    left: 9%;
    opacity: 0.175;
}
```

I want both the video and the music to pause whenever I click the #pause button, and for both of them to play again whenever I click the #play button.
I tried a lot of times with different corrections over my javascript:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid"),
pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause"),
playButton = document.getElementById("play"),
mus = document.getElementById("music");

playButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (vid.paused == false && mus.paused == false)
        return;
    else {
        vid.play();
        mus.play();
    }
});

pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (vid.paused == true && mus.paused == true)
        return;
    else {
        vid.pause();
        mus.pause();
    }
});
```

I am getting no errors/warnings whatsoever in my browser's console and also nothing happens when I click on the buttons. I have defined it in the index.html:

```
<script src="assets/js/buttons.js"></script>
```

Yes, it is in the right folder, as all other javascripts are there and they are working fine. I've put this after all others. I noticed that if I put it before the others, some of them stop loading and spit out errors.
Any idea what could it be?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your logic seems fine in isolation. If you add a `console.log()` to the event handlers does it appear?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Nope, it does not. I have doubts that the two images (buttons) cannot be clicked, like they are not on top. Not sure how to fix that, though. And I'm not sure if it actually is that.

Comment: That is your problem then; the events are not raised. Either they are being attached before the DOM is ready, or as you say, they are being covered by another element. You could try moving your script to just before `</body>` or setting the `z-index` on the CSS of those elements

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, as you said, `z-index` solved the problem. Partly. The video is being paused, but the music isn't. That is most probably because it is actually an embed. I am sorry to ask such a question, but how can an embed with a given ID be stopped?
EDIT: I've fixed it, just started using <audio> instead of embeds. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting for quite some time and also thanks to @RoryMcCrossan who commented, I've been able to solve the issue. 
I added `z-index` to the ids of the buttons, because as I had doubts, they couldn't be clicked as they were below other objects:

```
#play {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    opacity: 0.175;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#pause {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5%;
    left: 9%;
    opacity: 0.175;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

After doing that, the issue got solved in half. The video could be paused, but the music not. I opened the console, no errors, however, in sources -> my js file I saw that the functions `removeAttribute` and `stop()` for the music were not working. I read up a little and understood that embeds do not have the same properties as the background video, nor as audio. So I just resolved to giving up the `<embed>` and replaced it with `<audio>`:

```
<audio src="resources/bgsound.mp3" id="music" autoplay></audio>
```

That solved everything and the buttons work perfectly fine now. Both pause and play.